# Traversing trough array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm kinda new in JavaScript, I know that there are different ways how to traverse  array of objects, but I found a tutorial and didn't get this ${person.name} part. Code is:

```
let personData = [
  { name: "Dylan", age: 31 },
  { name: "Hannah", age: 17 },
  { name: "Dollan", age: 39 },
  { name: "Elle", age: 3 },
];

function loadTableData(personData) {
  for (let person of personData) {
    dataHtml += `<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>`;
  }
}
```

I tried to understand what exactly is happening so I put `${personData.name}` to console and I get `"undefined" = $3` My question is, why this works fine within for loop, but in console I'm getting undefined?

Comment: What don't you understand about `person.name`? `person` is the current object in the loop, and `person.name` is the value of the `name` property. So when `person == {name: 'Dylan', age: 31 }`, `person.name == 'Dylan'`

Comment: The `person` variable is local to the loop, it's created by `for (let person of personData)`. So it's not defined if you just type `person.name` in the console.

Comment: In your loop you write `person.name`, not `personData.name`.

Comment: Learn how to use the debugger, so you can stop the code and then "step through" every line. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/ Then you can just type `debugger()` in the code, and reload the page with the console opened (F12).

Comment: What is `dataHtml`? You neither declare, initialise nor use it.

Comment: Inside of your `for` loop add `console.log(person.name);`... I think it'll clear your confusion up for you. Or in console you would need to select an index like this: `personData[0].name` to see it outside of the loop.

Comment: Try in your console: personData[0].name and see what happens. What the for...of does is take each item of array and select a item as the variable you choose. If you have chosen for (let potato of pensonData) it would work as well. Potato would have been the name of the each object that only exists within the for loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, `personData` is the array of objects, to access each item you access it inside the loop with a local variable `person`. Console will log undefined for `${personData.name}` instead you can access an item of the array through index, try this `${personData[0].name}` which will print the vale of `name` property in your first item.

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over the personData object, you will get undefined with your given code. You can try the following:

```
personData.forEach(function (person ) {
     dataHtml += `<tr><td>${person.name}</td><td>${person.age}</td></tr>`;
});
```